# Prestashop - Import texture images for the color attribute

Tags: import, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm importing new products and combinations in my PrestaShop 1.7.5.1, the attribute for each products are size and colour.

Colour attributes are named like these: Black/Red, Pink/White, Pale Yellow/White.

For each one there is an image that can be used as texture, below the example:

[image]

I've tried to load manually one of them but I can't find the images reference in the database, is it possible to load with a script all the images as texture in the database? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

The PrestaShop linking between texture and colours is based on the colours id, so if you want to link specific texture (a jpg image) to a specific colour, you need to import the related image in the folder: /img/co, and they must be named with {colour_id}.jpg

Nothing needs to be added to the database.